# How to print a tree of processes that created by a fork command in c

Tags: c, process, tree, fork

I created a tree of forks by combining fork commands in C. The program that created the tree is:

```
int main(){

    (fork()&&(fork()&&(fork()||(fork()&&fork())&&fork())||(fork()||(fork()&&fork()))))||(fork()||(fork()&&fork()));

    while(1);

    return 0;
}
```

This command is written in a C file.  How can I print the tree of processes created by this code?

Comment: I think that using a function such as `forking()` which mainly calls `fork()` but also prints relevant information — either before or after the `fork()`, or possibly both — would be a reasonable way to generate the data you're seeking.  Presenting it is then a different problem.  It would be better for your system if you used `pause()` instead of `while (1);` — that allows other processes to get on with real work.  Because the processes all hang, you can also arrange to analyze the output from `ps` to get the process tree information (if these processes aren't tied up in busy loops).

Answer (score 1):

I would have the program print out the tree in Graphviz DOT format, as a directed graph. In your case, the output would be along the lines of

```
digraph {
    "a" -> "b";
    "a" -> "c";
    "b" -> "d";
}
```

where each process (except for the initial one) prints one line containing `->`: its own PID in quotes on the right, and its parents PID in quotes on the left.

The initial process prints the `digraph {` and `}` parts, but do note that each process must wait for its children in order for the closing `}` to be printed last. You can do that by saving the process ID before that line, and and after reaping all children, printing the closing `}` if this process ID matches the original process ID.

To reap the children, replace your infinite loop with for example

```
pid_t  p;

while (1) {
    p = wait(NULL);
    if (p == -1 && errno != EINTR)
        break;
}
```

which waits until all children of the current process have exited.

In Linux systems, your package/software manager will have the Graphviz package, so install it from there. (For non-Linux systems, see [graphviz.org](https://www.graphviz.org/).)

Run your program, but redirect the DOT output to a file, say `out.dot`. Then, run `dot -Tx11 out.dot` to view the graph interactively, or `dot -Tsvg out.dot > out.svg` to generate an SVG image (`out.svg`) that you can view in any browser for example.

Here is one possible .dot output a properly modified program can output:

```
digraph {
    "944" -> "945";
    "944" -> "946";
    "944" -> "947";
    "947" -> "950";
    "945" -> "948";
    "947" -> "951";
    "946" -> "949";
    "950" -> "953";
    "947" -> "952";
    "948" -> "956";
    "951" -> "955";
    "949" -> "957";
    "948" -> "954";
    "953" -> "958";
    "957" -> "963";
    "955" -> "964";
    "949" -> "959";
    "953" -> "961";
    "955" -> "962";
    "963" -> "968";
    "952" -> "960";
    "959" -> "966";
    "962" -> "969";
    "963" -> "965";
    "958" -> "973";
    "960" -> "971";
    "964" -> "967";
    "969" -> "975";
    "973" -> "979";
    "961" -> "970";
    "973" -> "978";
    "966" -> "974";
    "967" -> "982";
    "969" -> "976";
    "960" -> "972";
    "970" -> "984";
    "972" -> "985";
    "971" -> "980";
    "966" -> "977";
    "980" -> "986";
    "967" -> "981";
    "970" -> "983";
    "985" -> "988";
    "980" -> "987";
    "985" -> "989";
}
```